# C++ Linked List Display All

Tags: c++, string, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I'm new to C++ and currently experimenting about linked lists and I'm having trouble with displaying the multiple values in my program. The problem is in the DisplayAll function.

```
    struct node
    {
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
        string phonenumber;
        string dayofbirth;
        string monthofbirth;
        string yearofbirth;
        string age;
        string streetname;
        string city;
        string state;
        string zipcode;
        char ch;
        static int count;
        int count2;
        node* next;
    };

    class InfoBook
    {
    private:
        node* head;
        node* current;
        node* temp;

    public:
        InfoBook();

        void userPromptStatement();
        node* AddNode(node*);
        void DisplayAll();
        //node* SearchNode();
        //void sort(node*, int);
        void UpdateNode();
        //node* DeleteNode(node*);
    };

node* InfoBook::AddNode(nodePtr temp)
{ 
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string phonenumber;
    string dayofbirth;
    string monthofbirth;
    string yearofbirth;
    string age;
    string streetname;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;
    InfoBook ad;

       if(head != NULL)
        {
            current = head;
            while(current -> next != NULL)
            {
                current = current -> next;
            }
            current -> next = new node;
            current -> firstname = temp -> firstname;
            current -> lastname = temp -> lastname;
                     ////code here to add the other values////
            current -> zipcode = temp -> zipcode;
            current -> next -> next = nullptr;
            return current;
            ad.userPromptStatement();
        }
       else
        {
            head = new node;
            head -> firstname = temp -> firstname;
            head -> lastname = temp -> lastname;
                    ////code here to add the other values////
            head -> zipcode = temp -> zipcode;
            head -> next = nullptr;
            return current;
        }
}

    ////////////////////////////////DisplayAll/////////////////////////////////

    void InfoBook::DisplayAll()
    {
        current = head;
        int count = 1;
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
        string phonenumber;
        string dayofbirth;
        string monthofbirth;
        string yearofbirth;
        string age;
        string streetname;
        string city;
        string state;
        string zipcode;

            if(current == nullptr)
            {
                cout << "\n\n\No Record exists.";
            }
                while(current != NULL)
                {      ////////The problem is somewhere between here////////
                    cout << "Record # " << count << " : ";
                    cout << current -> firstname << endl;
                    cout << current -> lastname << endl;
                    cout << current -> phonenumber << endl;
                    cout << current -> dayofbirth << endl;
                    cout << current -> monthofbirth << endl;
                    cout << current -> yearofbirth << endl;
                    cout << current -> age << endl;
                    cout << current -> streetname << endl;
                    cout << current -> city << endl;
                    cout << current -> state << endl;
                    cout << current -> zipcode << endl;
                    cout <<"\n\n\n";
                    current = current -> next;
                    count++;
                }
    }
                            ///////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The program displays only 'Record # : ' but not the values. Any ideas?

```
//////////////////added//////////////////////
 node* temp = new node;
 node* current;
 char ch;
 int count2 = 0;
 ad.userPromptStatement();

 while(1)
 {
    cin >> ch;
    switch(ch)
    {
        case '1':
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n\nINSERT RECORD";
                        cout << "\n\nInput FIRST NAME: ";
                        cin.ignore();
                        getline(cin,firstname,'\n');

                        cout << "\nRecord inserted!";
                    current = ad.AddNode(temp);
                ad.userPromptStatement();
        break;

        case '2':
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n\nDISPLAY ALL\n\n";
            ad.DisplayAll();
            _getch();
            ad.userPromptStatement();
        break;
```

Comment: You use `current` for different things. Some of these things will leave it as `NULL` which means that some other things might stop working as it check for `current` being non-null.

Comment: Also, how do you *use* this functions? Please show us a complete (but small) example.

Comment: There are also other possible problems, like unreachable code (you `return` before calling `ad.userPromptStatement` for example).

Comment: Do you get 14 empty lines after "Record #:" ? If yes, it is because the data in the node is not populated. Focus on the input to AddNode.

Comment: @user3307862 Yes, I do get the empty lines.

Comment: @user3391677 - If you're new to C++, why are you attempting to code a linked list?  Not only is this not a beginner exercise, but if you want to utilize a linked list data structure in your real program, then you have std::list.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I started C++ a couple months ago. Can you tell me how I can use std::list with my code?

Comment: The code gets the firstname from the user. I do not see code where it populates the firstname in the node "temp". AddNode gets temp and if it is not populated with data.....

Comment: @user3391677 - I could post as an answer, but I don't want to discourage you from trying to code your own linked list.  It's just that I don't recommend beginners coding things like this.  To code a linked list *correctly* usually requires more experience than 2 months of C++.  Sure, you may get something working, but I can almost guarantee that the code will be easily broken.  So why give a false sense of accomplishment with such code?  Get the experience first, and even then you still should use what has already been coded, namely std::list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you desire to use a linked list, I recommend you not reinvent the wheel and instead use 
std::list.  You can still salvage most of your node class when using std::list.

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string phonenumber;
    string dayofbirth;
    string monthofbirth;
    string yearofbirth;
    string age;
    string streetname;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;
    char ch;
};

typedef std::list<node> NodeList;

class InfoBook
{
    NodeList nList;

    public:
        InfoBook();

        void userPromptStatement();
        void AddNode(node& theNode) { nList.push_back(theNode); }
        void DisplayAll();
};

void InfoBook::DisplayAll()
{
    NodeList::iterator it = nList.begin();
    while (it != nList.end())
    {
        node& curNode = *it;
        // now print out curNode in whatever way you see fit
        // ...
        ++it;  // go to nest node in the list
    }
}
```

Note how much shorter the code is, especially the AddNode() function.  The node class no longer needs to keep count of things, as the nList.size() will give you the number of nodes.

The sample above introduces you to the standard library containers (std::list) and iterators (the "it" in the DisplayAll function).  I didn't fill in the other InfoBook functions, as I'll leave it to you to do that, but hopefully you get the idea on how to finish up.

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem is here:

```
current -> next = new node;
current -> firstname = temp -> firstname;
current -> lastname = temp -> lastname;
        ////code here to add the other values////
current -> zipcode = temp -> zipcode;
```

In the above code you allocate a new node at `current->next`, but assign to the fields of `current`.

---

Another problem is that you don't actually initialize the fields in the node structure you use in the `AddNode` call.